# SoftLayer Endurance Storage Snapshot taking too long to return

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

when calling the SoftLayer API for taking an endurance storage, the  snapshots are taking 1 minute and more to return. If we prevent access to the filesystem during this time, this will not be acceptable from an availability perspective.

For comparison, when doing the same task in AWS, the CreateSnapshot returns immediately, and therefore the system downtime , is extremely short .

Is this issue related to the client libraries and would it be solved by using the REST API directly?

Answer (score 0):

The control portal uses the API to perform the tasks so if you use the REST API you will get the same result. I recomend you to submit a ticket to softlayer asking about why the snapshot is taking so much perhaps this is an issue with your device.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nelson. However, it was Softlayer support how told me to post a question here in the first place. Can you confirm, that the API should return within a few seconds, and that initiating/taking the snapshot should not show this blocking behavior?

Comment: if they told you that is because you submitted the ticket with "dev API" subject if you do that they always tell you post here, however if you concern is the time that is taking you should submit the ticket with another subjet.

Comment: In regard your question It should be the same take the snapshot using the API or the control portal becasuse both make a call to the same API method. this is the method if you want to try http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/createSnapshot you only need to perform a post call like this POST https://$Username:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Sotrage/$BlockStoreageID/createSnapshot

Comment: You can try use the method and see if there are differences. let me know if you have troubles using the method

Comment: Hi Nelson, I have the following update:
1. There is no difference between using the Portal or the Python API
2. An average "create_snapshot" API call takes ~15 seconds.

This was tested with a simple script, based on the SoftLayer Python API, and with a newly attached Endurance storage.
The API calls used are as follows:

softlayer_client=SoftLayer.Client(username=sys.argv[1],api_key=sys.argv[2])
snapshot_client=softlayer_client['Network_Storage']
snapshot_client.createSnapshot("testing", id=vol_id)

Answer (score 0):

**The time to take between snapshots are 1 minute, but the snapshot is instantaneous**, so it means that you will be able to access to the file system without interruption